# I have a list that contains dictionaries. How can i append to a specific key's value?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this

```
  mylist = [ {'Name': 'one', 'Lname': 'two'}, {'Name': 'foo', 'Lname': 'bar'} ]
```

Im looking for a way to append to a specific key's value. For example append to 'Name' in first dictionary the string 'newName' and have as a result `mylist = [ {'Name': 'one newName', 'Lname': 'two'}, {'Name': 'foo', 'Lname': 'bar'} ]`

I know that it's possible to change that value with something like myList[0]['Name'] = 'something' but what if i want to append to it ?

Comment: This question shows no search effort

Comment: Note that you don't technically "append" to a string, you *concatenate* it, which is equivalent to *extending* for other sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the add-assign operator:

```
myList[0]['Name'] += 'what you want to append'
```

Comment: It's not officially called "add-assign", that's just what I called it. I think technically it'd be "addition augmented assignment operator".

Comment: (removed my last comment - didn't want to cause a fuss, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the add-assign operator `+=`

```
myList[0]['Name'] += 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
old_name = mylist[0]["Name"]
mylist[0]["Name"] = old_name + "newName"
```

Comment: or use += as others have said

Comment: I don't think OP wants it at the beginning. OP said "But what if i want to append to it?"